# Async GetMany method in Repository

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, collections, repository-pattern

I have repository method which returns collection according to filter

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Now I want to write this method as Async. And this is my problem.
Should I change type of DbSet (`DbSet<T>` ) to something else or what is the correct solution?

```
protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

public Repository(AdminDbContext context)
{
    this.Context = context;
    this.DbSet = context.Set<T>();
}
```

---

UPD : `return query.ToListAsync();` - is it enough ? Thanks

Comment: This question can be easily answered by checking an Entity Framework tutorial or the documentation of `ToListAsync`. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no. I found answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj819165.aspx), you still use `DbSet`, but you use async extensions for accessing the set.

Here's an async version of your code:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetManyAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```